# Unable to make the booleanfield true through submit button in django

Tags: python, django

I'm a complete novice to django. I want to make the is_hod booleanfield of class retest in models,  true when I hit submit in the details page.How can it be possible.

details.html

```
<form action="{% url 'retest:accept' retest.id %} " method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^retest/(?P<retest_id>[0-9]+)/accept$' , views.accept, name='accept' )
```

views.py

```
def accept(request, retest_id):
    retest = get_object_or_404(Retest, pk=retest_id)
    try:
        selected_retest = Retest.objects.get(pk=request.POST[retest_id])
    except (KeyError, Retest.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'retest/details.html' , {'retest': retest, 'error_message': "error",})
    else:
        selected_retest.is_hod = True
        selected_retest.save()
    return render(request, 'retest/details.html' , {'retest': retest})
```

Comment: The ID is not present in `request.POST` - you should use the `retest_id` argument directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# views.py

def accept(request, retest_id):
    retest = get_object_or_404(Retest, pk=retest_id)
    # update is_hod attribute only if the request is a POST.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        retest.is_hod = True
        retest.save(update_fields=['is_hod'])
return render(request, 'retest/details.html' , {'retest': retest})
```